# EF 4.3 Context without repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to use EF directly in a business / service layer without using repositories but wondered where the best place to create / dispose the context if I want to make the class testable using a test DB?

Should it be using DI in the service constructor and mark the class as IDisposable and get rid of it there or just wrap each call in a using block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on your reluctance on a repository class, but this is where I've been creating a destroying the EF context for my service layer.

So for my MVC web app, I register the repository using Autofac with lifetimescope

```
builder
       .RegisterType<AccountRepository>()
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My account service will get a reference to a repository instance from the container and will have access to a single context throughout the life time of the web request.  Once the request is finished, Autofac will call dispose on the repository and clean up the context.

```
public sealed class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository, IDisposable
{
    private AccountContext _context = new AccountContext();

    public IList<AccountEntity> GetAccounts()
    {
        return _context.Accounts
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
    } 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gav.  I think you are doing what I am hoping to by having one layer under the MVC for data access, albeit I am calling it a service class.  I previously had BLL & DAL with Linq2SQL but feel I only need one layer.  How do you do joins or transactional updates with other repositories?